# Analytic determinant of a sparse 25x25 matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, sparse-arrays

I would like to compute the analytic determinant of the following sparse matrix

```
mat={
  {f[1, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[1, 2] + f[1, 6] + f[2, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, f[1, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[1, 3] + f[1, 6] + f[3, 6], f[1, 2] + f[1, 6] + f[2, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, f[4, 5], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, f[1, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[1, 4] + f[1, 6] + f[4, 6], 0, f[1, 2] + f[1, 6] + f[2, 6], 0, 0, 0, f[3, 5], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, f[1, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[1, 3] + f[1, 6] + f[3, 6], 0, f[1, 2] + f[1, 6] + f[2, 6], 0, 0, 0, q[1], 0, 0, f[4, 5], 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, f[1, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[1, 4] + f[1, 6] + f[4, 6], f[1, 3] + f[1, 6] + f[3, 6], 0, f[1, 2] + f[1, 6] + f[2, 6], 0, f[2, 5], 0, q[1], 0, f[3, 5], f[4, 5], 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[1, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[1, 4] + f[1, 6] + f[4, 6], 0, 0, f[1, 2] + f[1, 6] + f[2, 6], 0, 0, 0, q[1], 0, f[3, 5], 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[1, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[1, 3] + f[1, 6] + f[3, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[1, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[1, 4] + f[1, 6] + f[4, 6], f[1, 3] + f[1, 6] + f[3, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[2, 5], 0, q[1], 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[1, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[1, 4] + f[1, 6] + f[4, 6], f[1, 3] + f[1, 6] + f[3, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[2, 5], 0, q[1], 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[1, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[1, 4] + f[1, 6] + f[4, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, q[1]},
  {f[2, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {f[3, 6], f[2, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[2, 3] + f[2, 6] + f[3, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {f[4, 6], 0, f[2, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[2, 4] + f[2, 6] + f[4, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, f[3, 6], 0, f[2, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[2, 3] + f[2, 6] + f[3, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, q[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, f[4, 6], f[3, 6], 0, f[2, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[3, 4] + f[3, 6] + f[4, 6], f[2, 4] + f[2, 6] + f[4, 6], f[2, 3] + f[2, 6] + f[3, 6], 0, 0, 0, f[1, 5], 0, q[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, f[4, 6], 0, 0, f[2, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[2, 4] + f[2, 6] + f[4, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, q[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, f[3, 6], 0, 0, f[2, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[2, 3] + f[2, 6] + f[3, 6], 0, 0, 0, q[3], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, f[4, 6], f[3, 6], 0, 0, f[2, 6], 0, 0, 0, f[3, 4] + f[3, 6] + f[4, 6], 0, f[2, 4] + f[2, 6] + f[4, 6], f[2, 3] + f[2, 6] + f[3, 6], 0, 0, q[4], q[3], 0, f[1, 5], 0, q[2], 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, f[4, 6], f[3, 6], 0, 0, f[2, 6], 0, 0, 0, f[3, 4] + f[3, 6] + f[4, 6], 0, f[2, 4] + f[2, 6] + f[4, 6], f[2, 3] + f[2, 6] + f[3, 6], 0, 0, q[4], q[3], 0, f[1, 5], 0, q[2], 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[4, 6], 0, 0, 0, f[2, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[2, 4] + f[2, 6] + f[4, 6], 0, 0, 0, q[4], 0, 0, 0, 0, q[2]},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[3, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[4, 6], f[3, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[3, 4] + f[3, 6] + f[4, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, q[3], 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[4, 6], f[3, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[3, 4] + f[3, 6] + f[4, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, q[4], q[3], 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[4, 6], f[3, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[3, 4] + f[3, 6] + f[4, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, q[4], q[3]},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, f[4, 6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, q[4]}
};
```

The built in *Mathematica* routine takes too long. The trivial Laplace expansion as given for instance in the answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21061/how-to-get-the-determinant-and-inverse-of-a-large-sparse-symmetric-matrix) also takes too long. What should I do?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need the analytical form of this determinant?

Comment: This determinant comes up in the U-resultant calculation of a system of multivariate equations. The solutions for these equations are then obtained from a factorization of the determinant and looking at coefficients of the `q[x_]` terms.

Comment: Because the upper left 10x10 block is diagonal, it appears straightforward to reduce the determinant to 15x15.  It also may be possible to further reduce it to 9x9 without too much difficulty, although that matrix will not be sparse.

Comment: I think this might give the determinant. `lu = LUDecomposition[mat]; detfax = Apply[Times,Diagonal[lu[[1]]]];` Might be very slow to factor however.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using [the properties of Block matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices):

$$\det\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf A&\mathbf B\\\mathbf C&\mathbf D\end{pmatrix}=\det(\mathbf A)\det\left(\mathbf D-\mathbf C\mathbf A^{-1}\mathbf B\right)$$

To visualize your matrix:

```
mat1 = mat;
{mat1[[;; 10, ;; 10]], mat1[[;; 10, 11 ;;]],
 mat1[[11 ;;, ;; 10]], mat1[[11 ;;, 11 ;;]]} = Range@4; (* cool :) *)
Show[MatrixPlot[mat1], MatrixPlot[mat, ColorRules -> {0 -> Transparent}]]
```

[image]

Then:

```
a = mat[[;; 10, ;; 10]];
b = mat[[;; 10, 11 ;;]];
c = mat[[11 ;;, ;; 10]];
d = mat[[11 ;;, 11 ;;]];

rr = d - c.Inverse[a].b;
(* The next trick def is done for using less memory *)
r = SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; rr[[i, j]] =!= 0 -> x[i, j]}, Dimensions@rr];
detr = Det@r;
(* now we roll back the trick *)
realDetR = detr /. x[i_, j_] :> rr[[i, j]];
(* and the grand total is ... *)
totalDet = Det[a] realDetR;
```

Comment: It works here, but in general it is better to use `LinearSolve[]` instead of `Inverse[]` for this application: `d - c.LinearSolve[a, b]`

Answer (score 6):

Here is a slightly compacted reformulation of belisarius's answer:

```
a = Take[mat, 10, 10]; b = Take[mat, 10, -15];
c = Take[mat, -15, 10]; d = Take[mat, -15, -15];

rr = ArrayRules[d - c.SparseArray[LinearSolve[a, b]]];
detr = Det[SparseArray[rr /. (pos_ /; VectorQ[pos, IntegerQ] -> expr_) :>
                       (pos -> C @@ pos), Dimensions[d]]];
realDetR = detr /. (Most[rr] /. pos_ /; VectorQ[pos, IntegerQ] :> C @@ pos);
totalDet = Det[a] realDetR
```

`ArrayRules[]` is a very useful thing!