# Explicitly find a guaranteed factorization of large expression?

Tags: linear-algebra, factorization

Consider the large expression `LE` defined in this [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/40hqc5ubry3k43u/MyLargeExpression.rar?dl=0) (involving only linearly independent functions), or in this [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i81bmunw5jarkni/MyLargeExpressionShorter.rar?dl=0) (linear interdependence present but slightly shorter notation).
Expression `LE` contains variables `q[i]` with $i=1,2,3,4$ and coefficients consisting of `f[x, y]` terms with $x,y\in\mathbb{N}^+$. Overall, the expression `LE` above features each term appearing in the following list multiplied by some coefficient dependent on the `f[x, y]`:

```
vL = {q[1]^6, q[1]^5 q[2], q[1]^4 q[2]^2, q[1]^3 q[2]^3, q[1]^2 q[2]^4, q[1] q[2]^5, q[2]^6, q[1]^5 q[3], q[1]^4 q[2] q[3], q[1]^3 q[2]^2 q[3], q[1]^2 q[2]^3 q[3], q[1] q[2]^4 q[3], q[2]^5 q[3], q[1]^4 q[3]^2, q[1]^3 q[2] q[3]^2, q[1]^2 q[2]^2 q[3]^2, q[1] q[2]^3 q[3]^2, q[2]^4 q[3]^2, q[1]^3 q[3]^3, q[1]^2 q[2] q[3]^3, q[1] q[2]^2 q[3]^3, q[2]^3 q[3]^3, q[1]^2 q[3]^4, q[1] q[2] q[3]^4, q[2]^2 q[3]^4, q[1] q[3]^5, q[2] q[3]^5, q[3]^6, q[1]^5 q[4], q[1]^4 q[2] q[4], q[1]^3 q[2]^2 q[4], q[1]^2 q[2]^3 q[4], q[1] q[2]^4 q[4], q[2]^5 q[4], q[1]^4 q[3] q[4], q[1]^3 q[2] q[3] q[4], q[1]^2 q[2]^2 q[3] q[4], q[1] q[2]^3 q[3] q[4], q[2]^4 q[3] q[4], q[1]^3 q[3]^2 q[4], q[1]^2 q[2] q[3]^2 q[4], q[1] q[2]^2 q[3]^2 q[4], q[2]^3 q[3]^2 q[4], q[1]^2 q[3]^3 q[4], q[1] q[2] q[3]^3 q[4], q[2]^2 q[3]^3 q[4], q[1] q[3]^4 q[4], q[2] q[3]^4 q[4], q[3]^5 q[4], q[1]^4 q[4]^2, q[1]^3 q[2] q[4]^2, q[1]^2 q[2]^2 q[4]^2, q[1] q[2]^3 q[4]^2, q[2]^4 q[4]^2, q[1]^3 q[3] q[4]^2, q[1]^2 q[2] q[3] q[4]^2, q[1] q[2]^2 q[3] q[4]^2, q[2]^3 q[3] q[4]^2, q[1]^2 q[3]^2 q[4]^2, q[1] q[2] q[3]^2 q[4]^2, q[2]^2 q[3]^2 q[4]^2, q[1] q[3]^3 q[4]^2, q[2] q[3]^3 q[4]^2, q[3]^4 q[4]^2, q[1]^3 q[4]^3, q[1]^2 q[2] q[4]^3, q[1] q[2]^2 q[4]^3, q[2]^3 q[4]^3, q[1]^2 q[3] q[4]^3, q[1] q[2] q[3] q[4]^3, q[2]^2 q[3] q[4]^3, q[1] q[3]^2 q[4]^3, q[2] q[3]^2 q[4]^3, q[3]^3 q[4]^3, q[1]^2 q[4]^4, q[1] q[2] q[4]^4, q[2]^2 q[4]^4, q[1] q[3] q[4]^4, q[2] q[3] q[4]^4, q[3]^2 q[4]^4, q[1] q[4]^5, q[2] q[4]^5, q[3] q[4]^5, q[4]^6};
```

Since `LE` is the U-resultant of a system of multivariate equations, it is mathematically guaranteed to factor in the following fashion:

```
myFactoring = Product[Sum[C[j, i] q[j], {j, 1, 4}], {i, 1, 6}];
```

With coefficients of interest `C[j, i]` which will then be used to construct solutions to the multivariate system of equations. Expanding `myFactoring` we see that each variable combination from `vL` properly appears. Unfortunately, `LE` is so large and unwieldy that I do not know how to go about to find the explicit factorization. So far I could find out by other means that square roots will appear in the factorization. The `C[j, i]` might be complex depending on what the parameters `f[i, j]` are and always two out of the six factorized brackets will be complex conjugates of each other (assuming `q[i]` are real). Any suggestion on how to do it?

Comment: Is `LE` the `Det` of [91859](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91859/analytic-determinant-of-a-sparse-25x25-matrix)?

Comment: It is related to it. Multiplying the `Det` by a constant factor and dividing out a different determinant (basically also a constant) gives `LE`. So, yes, one could also factorize the `Det` keeping in mind that an extra overall factor dependent on the `f[x,y]` should appear then.

Comment: It may be useful to know that `q[i]` appears only in the combination `q[i] - (f[i, 6] q[1])/f[1, 6]` with `{i, 2, 4}`.  This can be seen by examining `rr` from the previous question.

Comment: Note also that `Sum[C[j, i] q[j], {j, 1, 4}]` can be scaled by an arbitrary factor `p[i]`, constrained only by `Product[p[i], {i, 6}] == 1`.  Does this matter?

Comment: Since the relevant solutions at the end of the day are given by `C[1,i]/C[4,i]` and `C[2,i]/C[4,i]` and `C[3,i]/C[4,i]` any such scaling would drop out. I am not sure if such scaling might be useful at intermediate steps though.